# High CPU load and temperature after installing Flatpak - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, temperature, cpu-load, flatpak

I did install Flatpak with its official [Quick Setup](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/).
 Also I've read [somewhere else](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/how-to-get-flatpak-apps-and-games-built.html) how to setup Nvidia driver on Flatpak (sadly I have an Nvidia Optimus video card!).
Everything was easy and like a peace of cake but the odd thing is after installing Flatpak package and rebooting whole system, my CPU load raised like every core gets to 100% and the CPU temperature went from max 63°C to at least 76°C. Also the official Nvidia driver showed 65°C for GPU temperature (before that it was hardly get to 53°C).

Did I do something wrong or it's normal? Also if not, can I fix it?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Samsung NP300E5C with nvidia-driver-390.116.